# Can a UEFI driver/service reserve a PCI device, preventing the OS from knowing about it and then use it after the OS boots

Tags: networking, tcp, uefi

Theoretically, if i was to have a extra network card in my computer would it be possible to create a UEFI driver/service which would prevent the about-to-boot operating system from knowing about the card (effectively reserving it), as well as start a service (eg. HTTP server) which would persist after the OS has booted?

Comment: Apologies, i thought i was asking this question in the unix exchange. Can this be moved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically no, standard UEFI firmware will cleanup almost everything before booting OS (calling ExitBootServices). What only remains is some data structures forwarded to OS - whole story f.e. on https://lwn.net/Articles/632528/

Also it can patch ACPI tables (which remains for OS) and "hide" that device, but driver not using info from ACPI can still communicate with this device. It can't start HTTP server and inject it somewhere along OS for sure.